# Excel: COUNTIF + OFFSET in another worksheet

Tags: excel, dynamic, offset, worksheet, countif

Not sure why this wouldn't work:

COUNTIF(OFFSET(OtherSheet!F5,0,0,4,1),"<10")

Trying to count values less than 10 in 4 rows of another worksheet.  Of course, I can use OtherSheet!F5:F8 instead of the OFFSET like so:

COUNTIF(OtherSheet!F5:F8,"<10")

and this works fine. but I'm trying to work up to where the "4" is dynamically determined.  But, I can't even seem to get the OFFSET to work correctly when the range is in another spreadsheet.

Thanks!
Derek

Comment: I gave a alternative, but your OFFSET works for me, what error is producing?

Answer (score 1):

Don't know about OFFSET, but it is volatile and I avoid it whenever possible.  I would use INDEX, which is not volatile:

```
=COUNTIF(Sheet1!$F$5:INDEX(Sheet1!$F$5:$F1040000,4),"<10")
```

Replace the `4` with the cell in which you want to place the size of the array.

[image]